# How do I select outerHTML in Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Here's the code

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL
$page = "http://indonesiax.co.id";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);

// Find all Images
$value = $html->find('div p img', 0)->outerhtml;
echo $value;
```

I want to select the outerHTML of This line of code but wont work

```
$value = $html->find('div p img', 0)->outerhtml;
```

if you guys know how to selecting outerHTML in HTML DOM Parser please share.

sample page for crawl https://indonesiax.co.id/

I want to display the output full with tag like this

```
<img src="https://files.edx.org/openedx-logos/edx-openedx-logo-tag-dark.png" alt="Powered by Open edX" width="140">
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by outerhtml, but I believe that would just be the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

solved.
should be like this

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL
$page = "http://indonesiax.co.id";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);
// Find all images
$altValue = $html->find('div p img', 0);
echo " src= $altValue->src<br /><br />";
echo " alt= $altValue->alt<br /><br />";
echo " width= $altValue->width<br /><br />";
```

the output be like

```
src= https://files.edx.org/openedx-logos/edx-openedx-logo-tag-dark.png
alt= Powered by Open edX
width= 140
```

Comment: What's the purpose to select outerHTML in Simple HTML DOM Parser?